# Managing References in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Although `System.IO` is not listed in the References that resides in the `Solution Explorer`, opening `Object Browser` shows this reference. And when a Nuget package installs and references a newer version and adds it to the References, VS complains during build:

> Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported.

But I just want the Nuget's System.IO, not .NET Framework's. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Core or .NET Standard?

Comment: @Dai .NET Standard